# selectize.js only manipulates dom of one tab when used with vue's v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, selectize.js

I'm using v-for to create many tabs of content with each one containing an input. Selectize works on the default tab, but when I change the tab, it goes back to a basic input. I want Selectize to the inputs of all tabs.

I've already tried triggering the selectize code $('#myInput').selectize({ ...
while on other tabs, but the code only seems to work upon creation of the site. It seems that something about the way that vue and selectize manipulate the dom is clashing.

```
template:`
   <div v-for="tab in tabs">
     <input id='myInput'>
   </div>

`

/* ... */

mounted: function(){
      $('#myInput').selectize({
      delimiter: ',',
      persist: false, 
      create: function(input) {
          return {
              value: input,
              text: input
          }
        }
      });
},
```

I expected this to apply selectize to the inputs of all tabs, but it only applies it to the input of the first tab.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ref` attribute instead of `id`.

```html
<div 
  v-for='tab in tabs' 
  v-show='currentTab === tab' 
  :key='tab'>
  <input ref='input'>
</div>
```

```
mounted () {
  this.$refs.input.forEach(input => {
    $(input).selectize({
      delimiter: ',',
      persist: false, 
      create (input) {
        return { value: input, text: input }
      }
    })
  })
}
```

With `v-show` the other tabs just hidden by none display so you don't need to reinitialize `selectize` again when change tab. But if you have some reason to use `v-if` you have to add watcher to reinitialize when tab changed:

```
watch: {
  currentTab () {
    Vue.nextTick(() => { // Defer operation to next render to make sure DOM element is finished render
      this.initSelectize()
    })
  }
}
```

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/4obhL6rf/)